# Finding the Value of Variable, given the value of the limit of the function

Tags: calculus, limits

If$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+a^3)+8e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+(1-b^3)e^{\frac{1}{x}}}  = \frac{-8}{7}$$
for at least one value of $a$ and $b$, then find $a$ and $b$.

I am able to find the value of b by dividing the numerator and denominator by the exponential. But I am unable to find $a$.

Hint:

> $a² + b³ - 3 = 6$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\begin{align}\frac{(1+a^3)+8e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+(1-b^3)e^{\frac{1}{x}}}& = \lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{(1+a^3)e^{-\frac{1}{x}}+8}{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}+(1-b^3)}\\\end{align}$

> $\lim_{x\to0^{-}}e^{\frac{1}{x}}=0$

> $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=0$

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a sneaky issue, as your limit really should be though of as two one-sided limits here, due to the fact that $\frac{1}{x}$ has a different limit from each side. So we split it up, and get

$$\lim_{x\downarrow0}\frac{1+a^3+8e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+(1-b^3)e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\overset{\xi=\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{\xi\to\infty}\frac{1+a^3+8e^\xi}{1+(1-b^3)e^\xi}=\lim_{\xi\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1+a^3}{e^\xi}+8}{\frac{1}{e^\xi}+1-b^3}=\frac{8}{1-b^3}$$

and

$$\lim_{x\uparrow0}\frac{1+a^3+8e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+(1-b^3)e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\overset{\xi=-\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{\xi\to\infty}\frac{1+a^3+\frac{8}{e^\xi}}{1+\frac{1-b^3}{e^\xi}}=1+a^3.$$

Since both of these have to equal $-\frac{8}{7}$, we can simply solve for $a$ and  $b$ as

$$a=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{15}{7}}\quad\text{and}\quad b=2.$$